# Prove that the space of sequences with limit $0$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Prove that $C_0$ (the space of sequences with limit $0$) is complete.

My effort: Let {$x_n$} be sequnce in $C_0$ converging to the limit $0$. As the {$0$} is in $C_0$ hence $C_0$ closed in $C$ which is complete. So $C_0$ so. Is this correct?

Please verify.

Comment: What is $C_0$ for you and above all:  what is your metric?!

Comment: $C_0$ set of null sequences.

Comment: Norm in $C_0$ is sup norm.

Comment: What you wrote can't answer the question. Since $C_0$ is a set of sequences, you need to take a Cauchy sequence of *sequences* and prove that it converges. What is $C$?

Comment: A cauchy sequence in $C_0$ is a "sequence of sequences" and can therefore be represented as $x_{nk}$ with $\lim_{k}x_{nk}=0$ and $\lim_{k_1,k_2\rightarrow\infty}\max_{n}|x_{nk_1}-x_{nk_2}|=0$. How do you construct your limit value $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n$ ?

Comment: @GregordeCillia where are you getting that factor of $n$ from in your second limit?

Comment: It is a second index. Maybe my notation is unclear

Answer (score 4):

To avoid confusing yourself with sequences of sequences, I recommend thinking of the elements of $C_0$ as **functions** $f:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$. Then the claim becomes: if $(f_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence of functions with respect to the uniform norm, there is $f\in C_0$ such that $f_k\to f$ uniformly.

The proof consists of two steps:

1. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the sequence $(f_k(n))_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence of *numbers*, hence has a limit. Denote this limit by $f(n)$, and you have a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$.
2. To show that $f\in C_0$: given $\epsilon>0$ pick $n$ such that $\|f-f_n\|<\epsilon/2$, and then pick $K$ such that $|f_n(k)|<\epsilon/2$ whenever $k\ge K$. Conclude that $|f(k)|<\epsilon$ whenever $k\ge K$.